# Oracle SYS or SYSTEM

Tags: oracle

Please I need to know what's the difference between sys and system in Oracle, and what's the meaninig of this line when trying to connect with user sys instead of system:
[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SYS and SYSTEM Schemas](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/tablecls.htm#CNCPT88803)

> All Oracle databases include default administrative accounts.
>   Administrative accounts are highly privileged and are intended only
>   for DBAs authorized to perform tasks such as starting and stopping the
>   database, managing memory and storage, creating and managing database
>   users, and so on.
>
> The SYS administrative account is automatically created when a
>   database is created. This account can perform all database
>   administrative functions. The SYS schema stores the base tables and
>   views for the data dictionary. These base tables and views are
>   critical for the operation of Oracle Database. Tables in the SYS
>   schema are manipulated only by the database and must never be modified
>   by any user.
>
> The SYSTEM administrative account is also automatically created when a
>   database is created. The SYSTEM schema stores additional tables and
>   views that display administrative information, and internal tables and
>   views used by various Oracle Database options and tools. Never use the
>   SYSTEM schema to store tables of interest to nonadministrative users.

```
28009, 00000, "connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER"
// *Cause:    connect SYS/<password> is no longer a valid syntax
// *Action:   Try connect SYS/<password> as SYSDBA or
//            connect SYS/<password> as SYSOPER
//
```

Comment: thanks @Balazs , I'm trying to understand so I could solve the user creation problem